# How to call chain subscription (RxJs) in ionic events

Tags: rxjs, observable, subscribe, ionic4, ionic-events

I have a BaseDataService class and it has a method for HttpGet requests.

```
protected Get<TResponse>(
    endPoint: string
  ): Observable<BaseResponse<TResponse>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<TResponse>(this.baseUrl + endPoint).pipe(
      map(data => {
        const response = <BaseResponse<TResponse>>{};
        response.Data = data;
        response.Errors = [];
        response.HasError = false;
        return response;
      }),
      catchError(errors => {
        const response = <BaseResponse<TResponse>>{};
        response.Errors = [];
        response.Errors.push(errors.error);
        response.HasError = true;
        return of(response);
      })
    );
  }
```

And I have a LocationDeviceDataService which extends BaseDataService and it has a method for Get LocationDevices

```
 getAll() {
    return this.Get<BasePaginatedResponse<LocationDeviceResponse>>(
      EndPoints.GET_LOCATIONDEVICES
    );
  }
```

And I am calling this method inside event ,

```
this.events.subscribe("connection-type:wifi", () => {
        this.locationDataService.getAll().subscribe(t => {
          localStorage.setItem('LOCATION_DEVICES', JSON.stringify(t.Data.items))
        });
      });
```

Everything is fine at first call , but when another events (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/)***publish*** for ***"connection-type:wifi"*** this.locationDataService.getAll().subscribe returns responses 1x,2x,4x etc. slower.

I am sure for nothing wrong in back-end.

Should unsubscribe or complete subscription ? If I should , I dont have any trigger for that.

Could you please tell me what is wrong in this code ?

Comment: What's `this.events`? Are you sure its `subscribe` method takes as a first argument a string?

Comment: @martin https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/ , yes it takes event name as string

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue.

I think you can not call observable method inside Ionic events so I changed my method to void. Everything is fine for now.